# C# Select only few member pairs from Object array and store it in Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, object

I have an Object array of my class (Item) like below,

```
class Item
{
    int id;
    int value;
    bool isSelected;
}

Item itemArr[] = new Item [MAXCOUNT];
```

To retrieve the selected Item ids and store into list, I am using below code

```
List<int> listOfItems = new List<int>();
listOfItems.AddRange(itemArr.Where(p => (p.IsSelected)
                            .Select(p => p.ID)).ToArray());
```

I have one more Dictionary which indicates item id as key and item value as value,

```
Dictionary<int,int> itemidValueMap = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

How to get item id and value pair and store it into this dictionary?

This question is not duplicate. I need to select only the elements which satisfies the condition and store only them in dictionary. But previous question says about adding all the elements into dictionary.

Comment: Your code wonßt even compile, as `Item.IsSeleceted` has no member `Select`. You probably missed a bracket. I supoose you mean `istOfItems.AddRange(itemArr.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.ID).ToArray());`.

Comment: You can't add a range of items of the type if `ID` as they are int and not `Item`. Please add compiling code

Comment: You probably want to add those items into your list that are selected - not just their ids. Omit the `Select` from your code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have edited my code now to List<int> from List<Item>. Hope this compiles.

Comment: @MongZhu : How to convert array to dictionary explains about getting all the array elements into dictionary. I need solution to select only the values which satisfies the condition and store them into dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To construct the dictionary use [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dictionary = itemArr.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                        .ToDictionary(key => key.id, value => value.value);
```

*If you have the same `id` a few times it will cause an exception (keys are not unique) so use  [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx) or first [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) and then `ToDictionary`.*

```
var lookup = itemArr.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                    .ToLookup(key => key.id, value => value.value);

var dictionary = itemArr.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                        .GroupBy(i => i.id)
                        .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Select(i => i.value));
```

---

As a side note you can populate the ID list a bit nicer:

```
var listOfItems = itemArr.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code selects all the itemid and value into dictionary. I need to select the items which has IsSelected value as true when adding it into dictionary. How to do ?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - Did this help you understand how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

To get the selected IDs your query should look like this:

```
List<int> selectedIDs = itemArr.Where(item => item.IsSelected).Select(item => item.id).ToList();
```

Note that the result is a `List<int>`, not a `List<Item>`.

To get your dictionary try this:

```
var idToValue = itemArr.ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.value);
```

This only works if your IDs are *unique*. If they are not, you'll need to group them, but I don't know how you want to aggregate the values of items with the same ID.

---

If you want that dictionary only for selected items, you simply insert the `Where` clause again:

```
var idToValue = itemArr.Where(item => item.IsSelected).ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
listOfItems.AddRange(itemArr.Where
                  (p => (p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.ID)).ToArray());
```

to

```
listOfItems.AddRange(itemArr.Where
                  (p => p.IsSelected).ToArray());
```

then

```
Dictionary<int,int> itemidValueMap = listOfItems.ToDictionary(item => item.id,
                                   item => item.value)
```